# hide wordpress products rating if empty

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I want to hide the stars rating below the title on the products where the reviews are empty. I want to hide only the stars without the ability to leave a new review.
I found a similar solution for hiding a different element and tried to adopt it.

I added this using a snippets plugin to add a class "hide-empty-stars" in body_class when the reviews are empty.

```
function check_for_empty_stars( $classes ) {
    global $product;
    $id = $product->get_id();

    $args = array ('post_type' => 'product', 'post_id' => $id);    
    $comments = get_comments( $args );

    if(empty($comments)) {
        $classes[] = 'hide-empty-stars';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'check_for_empty_stars' );
```

Then I hide the star-rating class using css

```
body.hide-empty-stars .star-rating{
    display: none;
}
```

It works but after a while I get a critical error and the log says that

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on null in /var/www/vhosts/my-domain.gr/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(505) : eval()'d code:3
```

What could cause this? Is there anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs when you are not on the product page. The `body_class` runs on every page but some pages do not have post ID - for example category pages. Your snippet should run only if there is an post ID defined. Let's say you are looking at page presenting some category - there is not `$product` variable but you try to call `get_id();` on `$product` so you get the error.

Maybe try to wrap it in if statement?

```
function check_for_empty_stars( $classes ) {
    global $product;
    if (!is_null($product)) {
        $id = $product->get_id();
    
        $args = array ('post_type' => 'product', 'post_id' => $id);    
        $comments = get_comments( $args );
    
        if(empty($comments)) {
            $classes[] = 'hide-empty-stars';
        }
    }
    
    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'body_class', 'check_for_empty_stars' );
```

Or just look for filter which will run only on product pages.
Also - you don't need any plugin like code-snippets. You can just place this code in the functions.php of your child-theme. Read about child-themes, these are good if you want to modify the theme and you will not lost your changes after updates. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/